# Linux: what is on each of my hard drives

Tags: disk-usage

I am about to get a new PC and will have Fedora 20 installed on it (with dual boot for a bit of Windows in case I really *have* to use it). It will have a new hard drive, but I want to keep the existing ones available for the data on them.

At present I have Fedora 12, and two internal hard drives whose details and partitioning I have forgotten. So, my question is: please, how can I find out what is on each? I can't understand the output of df and how it relates to the physical drives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of tools you can use to check the layout of a disk to see how it's partitioned. Given you're using an older distro in F12 some of these tools may not be present, so your mileage will vary. I have an ancient version of FC3 and can confirm that this tool is present which will do what you want.

*blkid*

```
$ blkid
/dev/hda1: LABEL="/boot" UUID="0a956929-XXXX-461a-XXXX-59e0XXXbcf0" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/dm-0: UUID="f51cdcd9-23XX-XXXX-XXXX-eb342c3b3fda" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/dm-1: TYPE="swap"
```

*fdisk*

You can also use `fdisk`:

```
$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/hda: 81.9 GB, 81964302336 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9964 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/hda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/hda2              14        9964    79931407+  8e  Linux LVM
```

*sfdisk*

You might be able to get your hands on `sfdisk` as well.

```
$ sfdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 30394 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1          0+      5       6-     48163+  de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2          6     267     262    2104515    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda3   *    268     292      25     200812+  83  Linux
/dev/sda4        293   30393   30101  241786282+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5        293+    305      13-    104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda6        306+  30393   30088- 241681828+  8e  Linux LVM
```

*cfdisk*

Finally there's `cfdisk` which is an interactive ncurses based application.

```
$ cfdisk
```

[image: ss #!]

#### Conclusions

There are other tools but these are 4 of the more common ones, in addition to `lsblk` as you move up the chain of newer releases of Fedora (and other distros).

#### References

- [List of Disk Partitioning Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_partitioning_software)

Answer (score 1):

The command `mount` by itself should tell you where each partition is mounted. If you are mounting raw partitions, it will talk about `/dev/sdaX`, `/dev/sdbX` and such, where `X` is a number identifying the partition.

If I were you, I'd just get a portable drive (such an old machine shouldn't have more than 1TiB disk total...) and get your tame geek copy *all* over. That way, if you need anything later, it'll be at hand. If that is too expensive, perhaps a full backup to a set of DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Listing partitions of a disk one choice is using command `fdisk` on each drive device (/dev/sd[ab] has been assumed) adapt for your drives.

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Just `sudo fdisk -l` would be enough, no need to manually iterating over all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `lsblk`, which will show you all your disks and partitions and how they are related. This is especially useful if intermediate layers like LVM or data-mapper are involved.